# How to make --no-ri --no-rdoc the default for gem install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I don't use the RI or RDoc output from the gems I install in my machine or in the servers I handle (I use other means of documentation).

Every gem I install installs RI and RDoc documentation by default, because I forget to set `--no-ri --no-rdoc`.

Is there a way to make those two flags the default?

Comment: It's not a good idea though. I recently needed to write code on the road and when I launched `gem server` I remembered that I had these in my `$HOME/.gemrc` and really killed me... Google isn't always there.

Comment: Depends on the context. It's a great idea if you can tether or you're doing this on a server that doesn't need gem documentation.

Comment: with pry one can use `show-source` as an alternative to generated docs. It will show inline comments, which are generally the same content as the ri/rdoc anyway.

Answer (score 1303, accepted):

You just add the following line to your local `~/.gemrc` file (it is in your *home* folder):

```
gem: --no-document
```

by

```
echo 'gem: --no-document' >> ~/.gemrc
```

or you can add this line to the global `gemrc` config file.

Here is how to find it (in Linux):

```
strace gem source 2>&1 | grep gemrc
```

The `--no-document` option is documented in [the RubyGems CLI Reference](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#installupdate-options).

Comment: Anyway to make this a system wide default without editing /etc/skel and every user's home directory?

Comment: /etc/gemrc didn't work for me, but .gemrc did. I wonder if it's rvm specific that it doesn't read the system gemrc?

Comment: Yea I'm using RVM and `/etc/gemrc` doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I think opinion was split on the default so it was never changed.

Comment: @gdelfino's answer is the least obtrusive

Comment: deprecated - please see my answer

Comment: Use `ruby -e "require 'etc';puts Etc.sysconfdir"` to determine the path to your `gemrc` config file.

Comment: If ruby was compiled with a prefix like `--prefix=/opt/ruby`, then the config file path will be `/opt/ruby/etc/gemrc` (confirmed with ruby 2.3.1)

Comment: I didn't have any `gemrc` but my system was quite happy to use a brand new one at `~/.gemrc`.

Comment: On FreeBSD,  `truss gem source 2>&1 | grep gemrc | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'` is the magic incantation to give you the relevant paths directly.

Comment: To find your gemrc file, run `gem env` and find the displayed `SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY` output field. Create or edit the gemrc file in that directory.

Answer (score 507):

From [RVM’s documentation](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/):

> Just add this line to your `~/.gemrc` or `/etc/gemrc`:

```
gem: --no-document
```

---

**Note:** The original answer was:

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri 
update: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

This is no longer valid; the RVM docs have since been updated, thus the current answer to only include the `gem` directive is the correct one.

Comment: [Since RubyGems version 2.0.0preview2](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/History.txt), you can instead use `--no-document` or `--document=rdoc` for just rdoc.

Comment: `/etc/gemrc` doesn't seem to work in practice, and [the documentation](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11) agrees with it.

Comment: `/etc/gemrc` will work for RVMs binary rubies because they use `--sysconfdir=/etc` you could build your rubies with it too like this: `rvm install 2.0.0 -C --sysconfdir=/etc` to get `/etc/gemrc` working for compiled rubies, otherwise use `$MY_RUBY_HOME/gemrc`.

Comment: I disagree with @mpapis's edit on Jun 20, 2013.  He totally changed this answer and there were lots of people that voted for it because they thought it was better than the accepted answer.  The person who posted this answer explicitly wrote that they do not want to add those two options to every gem command because it breaks some commands.  Before @mpapis totally changed the answer, the code in the answer was:  `install: --no-rdoc --no-ri\nupdate:  --no-rdoc --no-ri`   @mpapis, why did you change the RVM documentation and also change this answer?

Comment: because it is true, there is no reason to keep two separate lines, keeping track of multi project compatibility is tricky - and the RVM docs get sometimes updated when we find something is off - like in this case, it is not true that rubygems would behave wrong, it's all fine to use `gem:` instead of two separate entries.

Comment: RVM docs say to use `rvm_gem_options` in `~/.rvmrc`  ie. to disable docs `export rvm_gem_options="--nodocument"` or to enable docs `export rvm_gem_options="--document rdoc,ri"`

Comment: Use `ruby -e "require 'etc';puts Etc.sysconfdir"` to determine the path to your `gemrc` config file.

Comment: This one is deprecated see http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install

Answer (score 190):

Note that `--no-ri` and `--no-rdoc` have been deprecated according to the new [guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_install). The recommended way is to use `--no-document` in `~/.gemrc` or `/etc/gemrc`.

```
install: --no-document
update: --no-document
```

or

```
gem: --no-document
```

Answer (score 103):

On Linux (and probably Mac):

```
echo 'gem: --no-document' >> ~/.gemrc
```

This one-liner used to be in comments here, but somehow disappeared.

Comment: You should use `>>` in case the user already has a `~/.gemrc`.

Comment: Is there a difference between this `echo 'gem: --no-doc --no-ri' >> ~/.gemrc` and the one you wrote or both have same effect?

Comment: @Lykos `--no-doc --no-ri` is deprecated (see http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_install for options)

Answer (score 44):

## /home/{user}/.gemrc

```
---
:update_sources: true
:sources:
- https;//rubygems.org
- https://gems.rubyforge.org/
- https://gems.github.com
:benchmark: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:backtrace: false
:verbose: true
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

http://webonrails.com/2008/12/03/skiping-installation-of-ri-and-rdoc-documentation-while-installing-gems/

Comment: Thanks for this example, perfect to help me strip out the embedded Ruby that I copied & pasted at some point and then resulted in psych errors while installing RubyGems 1.8.10 under Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Please don't post "first result on Google" replies. The first result on Google now shows your reply, self-proving why you shouldn't do this. Thanks, of course, for your answer.

Comment: Actually, "first result on Google" shows: ""first result on Google" shows: ""first result on Google" shows: ""... ERROR: Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have to add my thanks for steve's comment (above). I was pulling my hair out as to why I could not install the latest RubyGems. Turns out I had a malformed .gemrc file as well. I kept getting this error: ../.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse': couldn't parse YAML at line 2 column 10 (Psych::SyntaxError)

Comment: and if you type "google" into google you'll break the internet

Comment: `---`

`    :update_sources: true `

`    :sources: `
    - https://rubygems.org/
    #- https://gems.rubyforge.org/
    #- https://gems.github.com
    :benchmark: false`   :bulk_threshold: 1000
`    :backtrace: false
`   :verbose: true`
`    gem: --no-document`
`    
With https :)

Answer (score 33):

On Windows XP the path to the .gemrc file is

```
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\gemrc
```

and this file is not created by default, you should create it yourself.

Comment: Under Windows 7 it's C:\ProgramData\gemrc

Comment: the win7 location works for windows 200. Also make sure you have "Hide extensions for known file types" off it wont pick up gemrc.txt.... facepalm

Answer (score 16):

A oneliner for the windows 7 users:

`(echo install: --no-document && echo update: --no-document) >> c:\ProgramData\gemrc`

Answer (score 10):

You can specify default options using the `.gemrc` configuration file.

[Documentation about gem configuration file](http://rubygems.org/read/chapter/11)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned above, put `gem: --no-document` in your gem file. However, the system-wide gemrc will not always necessarily go into `/etc/gemrc`. If you are using RVM, or you have Ruby installed under `/usr/local/bin`, it needs to go in a different location. You can find this location by running `irb` and typing...

```
require 'rubygems'
Gem::ConfigFile::SYSTEM_WIDE_CONFIG_FILE
```

See the original post on this over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219668/disable-rdoc-and-ri-generation-by-default-for-rubygems-1-8-x/22888918#22888918).

Comment: Oneliner: `ruby -rrubygems -e'puts Gem::ConfigFile::SYSTEM_WIDE_CONFIG_FILE'`

Answer (score 5):

Step by steps:

To create/edit the .gemrc file from the terminal:

```
vi  ~/.gemrc
```

You will open a editor called vi. 
paste in:

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

click 'esc'-button.

type in:

```
:exit
```

You can check if everything is correct with this command:

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit ~/.gemrc
```

Comment: To clarify, that last command is OS X specific. It opens the `~/.gemrc` file in a texteditor.

Comment: ~ is representation for home directory. (the following stuff in caps are environment variables) Order of checking directories for .gemrc: 1. Use HOME if it is defined. 2. Use USERPROFILE if it is defined. 3. Use HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH together if they are defined. 4. Use the path you get by having Ruby expand “~”. 5. Use “C:/” if you are on a Windows machine. That is per: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/12

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` to edit your own user's `~/.gemrc`.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows7 the .gemrc file is not present, you can let Ruby create one like this (it's not easy to do this in explorer).

```
gem sources --add http://rubygems.org
```

You will have to confirm (it's unsafe).
Now the file is created in your userprofile folder (c:\users\)

You can edit the textfile to remove the source you added or you can remove it with

```
gem sources --remove http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users, Ruby doesn't set up .gemrc file. So you have to create .gemrc file in your home directory (`echo %USERPROFILE%`) and put following line in it:

```
gem: --no-document
```

As already mentioned in previous answers, don't use --no-ri and --no-rdoc cause its deprecated. See it yourself:

```
gem help install
```

Answer (score 0):

~/.gemrc file

```
---
gem: --no-document
:update_sources: true
:sources:
- https://rubygems.org/
:benchmark: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:backtrace: false
:verbose: true
```

Use HTTPS and a known source. An improvement over the above answer.

PS: I tried to post the comment and could not get it to format nicely. Finally resorted to posting a new answer.