# How do I make --no-ri --no-rdoc the default for gem install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make --no-ri --no-rdoc the default for gem install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install)

I never use ri nor rdoc and they take too long to install. Is there a config file somewhere that will let me do this

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

to your ~/.gemrc file

Comment: Thanks. A very quick and concise answer. Points given!

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the ['.gemrc' config file](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11).

Answer (score 5):

you can alias your gem command for something like

```
alias geminst='gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc'
```

Comment: Points given for taking the time but the .gemrc is the correct answer - thanks

Comment: My points given for answering in a general, reproducible way that works for all command line utilities :P

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows XP the path to gemrc file is "c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\gemrc". And this file is not created by default, you should create it yourself.

Comment: Under Windows 7 it's C:\ProgramData\gemrc

Answer (score 2):

To add those flags to `~/.gemrc` only for those specific commands that need them:

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
update: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```