# Why does it take longer to install RDOCSs and RIs than the actual gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc, ri

It is always frustrating to install a gem and wait 2 seconds for the gem to install and then wait 30 seconds for the docs, which I never use(Google, anyone?).  Why do we force this convention upon ourselves when the local docs normally aren't even beneficial?

I know you can use `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc` to skip that step but is there a way to simply skip the docs by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make --no-ri --no-rdoc the default for gem install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789376/how-do-i-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install)

Comment: It's a good question, but one for a Ruby mailing list, not s/o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the flags to your `~/.gemrc` file.

From [the docs](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11):

> `gem` looks for a configuration file `.gemrc` in your home directory,
>   although you can specify another file on the command-line if you wish
>   (with the `--config-file modifier`). Only one configuration file will be
>   processed: the rightmost one on the command-line, or the default
>   `$HOME/.gemrc`, or none at all.
>
> There are three things you can specify in the configuration file:
>
> - command-line arguments to be used every time `gem` runs
> - command-line options for "RDoc" (used when generating documentation)
> - `GEMPATH` settings
>
> The config file itself is in "YAML" format. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> gem:  --local --gen-rdoc --run-tests
> rdoc: --inline-source --line-numbers
> gempath:
>  - /usr/local/rubygems
>  - /home/gavin/.rubygems
> ```
>
> The effects of such a config file would be:
>
> - `gem` only runs "local" operations (unless you specify `--remote` or `--both` on the command-line)
> - `gem` generates RDocs and runs unit tests every time it installs something (good idea!)
> - when it generates RDocs, the given arguments will be used
> - `/usr/local/rubygems` and `/home/gavin/rubygems` will be used as your `$GEM_PATH` setting

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the top-line question.  Why does it appear that RDocs take much much longer to install than the actual code?