# Problems installing rdoc, irb, bluecloth, chronic on fedora 12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, rdoc, chronic, bluecloth

What do these errors mean?

```
[root@localhost config]# gem install bluecloth
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bluecloth:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
can't find header files for ruby.


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bluecloth-2.0.7 for 
inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bluecloth-2.0.7/ext/gem_make.out
[root@localhost config]#
```

And this

```
[root@localhost config]# gem install chronic
Successfully installed json_pure-1.4.3
Successfully installed rubyforge-2.0.4
Successfully installed hoe-2.6.0
Successfully installed chronic-0.2.3
4 gems installed
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rdoc-2.5.8/lib/rdoc/ruby_lex.rb:67: warning: 
parenthesize argument(s) for future version
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DocumentError)
    ERROR: RDoc documentation generator not installed: no such file to load -- irb/slex
[root@localhost config]#
```

I have installed rdocs using "yum install ruby-rdocs". But I don't understand what this error means

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
yum install ruby-devel ruby-irb ruby-rdoc ruby-ri
```

Although the former command fixes both issues, take in mind that in the case of the second error message, you can had also skip the documentation by adding `--no-rdoc`.

**April 2017:**
`--[no-]rdoc` argument has been deprecated as explained in `gem install --help`. You now have to use `--no-document` at each gem installation or store this in your `~/.gemrc` as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install#answer-1386014).

Comment: Thanks that worked. And how can I get ruby-1.9.1 installed using yum?
`yum install ruby --version=1.9.1` doesn't work.  I get this error `No package ruby-1.9.1 available.`

Comment: IIRC there are no 1.9.x ruby packages in fedora.. nor does it compile cleanly (disappointed as well).

Comment: Okay, that's news. Anyway thanks, atleast my bigger problems are fixed