# How to remove installed ri and rdoc?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How can I remove the `ri` and `rdoc` of installed gems? Thanks

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can simply remove the `doc` directory in the RubyGems installation directory.

```
rm -r `gem env gemdir`/doc
```

On Mac OS X by default, it's `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/doc`.

Keep in mind that there might be several installation directories for RubyGems.

- RubyGems will try to install to your user directory (something like `~/.gem/ruby/1.8/`) if it can't access the normal installation directory (e.g. you installed a gem without `sudo`).
- RVM also installs RubyGems for each Ruby it installs which will contain a `doc` directory containing `rdoc` and `ri` files (e.g. `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview1/doc`).

This will merely remove existing files, but new ones will come with new installations anyway, unless you use the `--no-document` flag for gem install or [make it a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-default-for-gem-install).

Comment: `--no-ri --no-rdoc` has been deprecated in favor of `--no-document`, but this answer works the best.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me when I tried this:

```
gem rdoc <gem name> --no-ri --overwrite
```

Then you can remove only ri of the gem, and leave the gem itself. I don't see we need any other way around for this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12968780)

Comment: Do you think I didn't understand the question? The question was "How can I remove the ri and rdoc of installed gems?" :)

Comment: You asked the OP to *try* something, which sounds like a guess, and hence a comment. If you are sure of what you are writing in your answer, I don't see why you'll use such words.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem to, after thinking it would be a good idea to have some local rdoc for the train etc, I completely filled up my disc!

So, I bit the bullet, and did it (**the hard way**).

First, this is how I got in this stupid predicament :-

```
$ gem install rdoc-data
$ rdoc-data --install
$ gem rdoc --all --overwrite
```

To undo this, I thought I'd uninstall the gems, and then install them as needed (but without rdoc!)

1. Get list :-

   ```
   $ gem list

   *** LOCAL GEMS ***

   aasm (2.1.1)
   actionmailer (3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 2.3.8, 2.3.5)
   actionpack (3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 2.3.8, 2.3.5)
   active_support (3.0.0)
   ... +100 ...
   ```
2. Copy and search/replace `\(.*\)` with '\'
3. Bulk uninstall :-

   ```
   $ gem uninstall actionmailer \
   actionpack \
   active_support \
   ... 100 more ...
   ZenTest \
   -a -x -I
   ```
4. Watch as the disc gains GB's of free space! (~11GB!)

Twas a stupid idea in the first place, and my solution may be just as much so, but it worked.