# How do I find the meaning of Ruby operators without using text?

Tags: ruby, operators

How do you find information (via Google, preferably) about the usage of operators in code?  In this case, I want to find the meaning of this code in Ruby.

```
x = [1,2,3]
x.send :[]=,0,2
x[0] + x.[](1) + x.send(:[],2)
```

I want you to teach me how to fish -- do not tell me what the operators do.  When I go to Google and try to search for the notation, I get examples or tutorials that don't cover the particular usage.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165786/how-to-search-for-punctuation-that-gets-ignored-by-google says that Google dismisses such notation; the way that I'm looking for an "answer" is to ask for at least one successful walkthrough from someone that can take the above code and say "Here is how I find out what the operators do".

Example of my unsuccessful searches.

- I search for *Ruby :[]=* and add/remove terms like *notation*, *operator*, *colon*, *bracket*, *square brackets*, and can't find usage of these operators in this way.
- I search for *ruby . notation*, add/remove terms like *period*, *dot*, *parenthesis*, etc.
- I search for cheat sheets.  Find the cheat sheet to Ruby on Rails default directory structure, regex expressions, etc., but still not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried the `ri` command-line utility?

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%5B%5D%3D and http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: x is an Array and 'send' (which is somewhat searchable) is used to call a method on an object.  So, you can head to ruby-doc.org and check Array's list of methods for []=.  If that fails you can check the Array's ancestors for it.

Comment: @RayToal, what software are you assuming I've installed for me to use a command-line utility?  I'd love to install it.

Comment: @muistooshort: thanks, I really like what symbolhound is trying to do and I hope our fellow engineers start explaining answers such that definitions follow.

Comment: A ruby installation normally comes with irb, ri, rdoc, and testrb.  If you installed "just ruby" on your own, or are using a stripped down installation from others, you might not have it.  But it should be there.  In fact [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941005/how-to-remove-installed-ri-and-rdoc) actually asks how ri and rdoc can be _removed_! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so hard not to tell you (I will if you ask).

Get a Ruby book. Try the Pickaxe, it has an entire section on Ruby operators, metaprograming, language reference, etc.

Comment: Roger; get The Pickaxe book (http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby), look up the section on Ruby operators, metaprogramming, and language references, and I will find it all.  Thanks!

Comment: @Danny: Sure. It's a really great book. I call it the Ruby bible.