# How to remove ri and RDoc documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc

How to remove already installed ri and RDoc documentation

```
Installing ri documentation for metric_fu-4.1.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for progressbar-0.20.0...
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove installed ri and rdoc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941005/how-to-remove-installed-ri-and-rdoc)

Comment: Another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2944084/397336

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are OK with manually removing it, it is somewhere in `..../lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/doc/` - the actual path depends on OS you use and how you install ruby.