# Disable rdoc and ri generation by default for rubygems 1.8.x

Tags: ruby, rubygems

There are a lot of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-default-for-gem-install) for this question that work under older versions of rubygems, but what is the recommended procedure for Rubygems 1.8.x? I have an `/etc/gemrc` file that looks like this:

```
gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

These options seem to be ignored during any `gem install`.

**Update:**

After doing some more digging, it seems the problem is related to `rvm` which partitions not just the various versions of ruby, but their associated configuration files, too. To check where the config file should go, use `irb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
Gem::ConfigFile::SYSTEM_WIDE_CONFIG_FILE
# => "/opt/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/etc/gemrc"
```

Comment: Nice update, but it does return "true" for me :-(

Comment: Ah, the "Update" section worked for me! It should be included in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to put the following in your `~/.gemrc` or `/etc/gemrc` file

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Comment: Wait, what? `/etc/.gemrc`? Still doesn't work for me even with that highly irregular name.

Comment: It does work if in `~/.gemrc` but I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: In [the source](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb) it seems to refer to `/etc/gemrc`, generally, but `rvm` causes confusion. Updated my question with notes.

Comment: Hi, I updated my post to refer to /etc/gemrc - mistyped that second . in the original post. The main point is that the command should be 'install: ...' not 'gem: ...'

Comment: With regards to RVM you will definitely find /etc/gemrc of little use and ~/.gemrc will be more useful. RVM is really meant to partition your ruby installations and configurations - as you point out in your update the SYSTEM_WIDE_CONFIG_FILE is located in an entirely new directory.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is dependent on where Ruby--and by extension gem--is installed in general, not just with RVM. I installed Ruby from source. The default install location when your are building from source is `/usr/local/bin`, so I installed Ruby there. Naturally this installs gem and all the other tools that come with Ruby in the same directory as well. I had my gemrc under `/etc`, but it didn't start working until I moved it to `/usr/local/etc` instead.

I later re-installed Ruby under `/usr/bin` instead `/usr/local/bin` and got the same result. It is now looking for gemrc under `/usr/etc` instead of `/usr/local/etc`. The gem tool must be looking for a path relative to where it's installed like `../etc` when searching for the system-wide gemrc file.

Answer (score 0):

I have the identical file but it's in ~/.gemrc and it works for me on RubyGems 1.8.5. I'm using RVM/Ruby 1.9.2 if that makes any difference.