# Creating a new rails 3 project over a proxy in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My computer works on a proxy. So in order to install gems I use the following command

```
gem install -p http//#{proxy-server}:#{port} rails
```

If i use the normal gem install command, I get an error `could not find gem`. I installed rails 3.1 today and tried to create a new project. Half the way while creating the files, the generator started executing `run  bundle install`  and ended up giving the same error

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not reach rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'turn (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

The generator is trying to install some gems without proxy. How can I override this existing functionality? I want the generator to use `gem install -p http//#{proxy-server}:#{port} #{gem}` instead of `gem install #{gem}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the given option to your [gemrc file](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11)

```
gem: -p http//#{proxy-server}:#{port}
```

Under unix this file is located under `~/.gemrc`, for windows I don't know, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-default-for-gem-install/3135423#3135423) should be

```
# Under windows XP
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\gemrc 
# Under Windows Vista/Seven
C:\ProgramData\gemrc for windows Vista/Seven
```

The rc file needs to be created if not present.