# Error when creating new Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, installation

I installed the Rails installer. Now I'm trying to create a new Rails project. When I do

```
C:\Sites> rails new demoproj
```

I get this error:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not reach rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'turn (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are installing rails over proxy. This maybe what you are looking for:

> Add the given option to your gemrc file

```
gem: -p http//#{proxy-server}:#{port}
```

[Creating a new rails 3 project over a proxy in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281047/creating-a-new-rails-3-project-over-a-proxy-in-windows)

Comment: thanks a lot friend, but i am not able to find gemrc file, is it same as C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin\gem file

Comment: I'm not Windows user so I'm not sure about this. try: _C:\ProgramData\gemrc_ for windows Vista/7. *The rc file needs to be created if not present* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281047/creating-a-new-rails-3-project-over-a-proxy-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

in a general way, that problem means you need to do a `bundle install`. no clue if its a windows specific issue though, there should be an automatic bundle after it creates the project.