# Using --no-rdoc and --no-ri with bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

When using `gem install gem_name` I can pass `--no-rdoc` and `--no-ri` switches to skip generating RDoc/RI documentation for the gem on install.

Is there a similar way to do this with `bundle install`?

Comment: As explained by Timbinous (2nd most voted answer), Bundler does this by DEFAULT

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Make a file `~/.gemrc` and put this in it:

`gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri`

That should make it apply whenever you run the `gem` command. (Even from `bundle install`)

Comment: should it be `gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri` or `:gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri`?

Comment: I copied and pasted what I have in my file, and that has been working for me for a while

Comment: Order doesn't matter, btw.  It's a list of command line flags to pass to gem.

Comment: the updated config is `--no-document`

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2018/12/25/ruby-2-6-0-released/
https://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/

Answer (score 273):

Bundler doesn't include rdoc and ri.  There is nothing you need to do.

Comment: So I see I'm downvoted 5 times.  Can anyone explain how I am wrong?  Bundler does not include RDoc and RI files when you install gems using `bundle install`.  People wanted this as a feature to allow you to install the documentation but they just don't allow it.

Comment: Timbinous [is right](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/383). It is not only correct, it should be the accepted answer because it actually answers the question. Damn shame people are herd-downvoting a correct answer when they know nothing.

Comment: Just so I'm clear Cyril. When he asks is there a similar way to do this with bundle install?  Telling him that bundler already does this for you by default is not actually solving his problem. He never had a problem to begin with. I was telling him that.

Answer (score 18):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7662245/109618 for a better `~/.gemrc`:

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri 
update:  --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Answer (score 18):

The up-to-date setting for `~/.gemrc` is

```
gem: --no-document
```

But as pointed out, this is already `bundler`'s default.

Comment: Works with gem 2.x

Comment: Since Ruby 2.5 ["Merge RubyGems 3.0.1. The --ri and --rdoc options have been removed. Please use the --document and --no-document options instead."](https://archive.ph/XBiY9). All the other answers are outdated.