# How to install Rails without docs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I installed RoR on my Mac using `sudo gem install rails`.  That command will download the docs.  Which switch can I use to not download any docs during installation?

Also, is there a way to remove all the docs after installation?

Comment: You can make it a gem install default.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535737/using-no-rdoc-and-no-ri-with-bundler

Comment: `gem install rails --no-document`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this in your terminal:

```
echo "gem: --no-document" >> ~/.gemrc
```

you can get more information [Faster Gem Installation](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use  `--no-document`.

To to make it default check [How to make --no-ri --no-rdoc the default for gem install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install)