# issue occurring while installing gem

Tags: rubygems

I am trying to install '''sudo gem install soap4r'''

But am facing the below issue..

```
Successfully installed httpclient-2.2.4

Successfully installed soap4r-1.5.8

2 gems installed

Installing ri documentation for httpclient-2.2.4...


RDoc failure in lib/httpclient.rb at or around line 405 column 16

Before reporting this, could you check that the file
you're documenting compiles cleanly--RDoc is not a
full Ruby parser, and gets confused easily if fed
invalid programs.

The internal error was:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `name' for #<RubyToken::TkLPAREN:0xb6598024>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't worry about it too much, it only failed trying to install the ri documentation for the gem, but as it states, the gem itself installed successfully. If you don't use ri/Rdoc, you can pass `--no-rdoc --no-ri` when running `gem install` to skip installing the local documentation, or you can [modify your `.gemrc` file to make it the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-default-for-gem-install).

Comment: Thanks for your update.. i have tried "sudo gem install soap4r --no-rdoc". but still the issue occurs

Comment: @sangeethkumar Sorry, it's probably blowing up on installing both ri & Rdoc documentation. See my updated answer and let me know if that helps.