# Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken

Tags: ruby, flutter, dart, cocoapods

How can I resolve the message `Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping Pod install. You appear to have cocoa pods installed but its not working.`?

The issue:

- It works fine if I create a new project and run it on IOS but from the previous projects it doesn't work on IOS.
- If I open the runner file from Xcode it launches but doesn't launch from android studio.

Therefore, when do pod install in the file it gives me this error:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.2.2/lib/date_core.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.2.2/lib/date_core.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.2.2/lib/date_core.bundle (LoadError) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'

So can you explain how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix this psych error reading ruby and cocoapods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085362/how-can-i-fix-this-psych-error-reading-ruby-and-cocoapods)

Answer (score 0):

From: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54962#issuecomment-635443559

> Resolved: Turns out it wasn't an issue with cocoapods per se. I did
> three things:
>
> 1. sudo gem update
> 2. I fired up Xcode which I had forgotten I had updated
>    and it required additional components to be installed.
> 3. I restarted visual studio code
>
> After that everything worked just fine.

Comment: But I get this error Before reporting this, could you check that the file you're documenting
has proper syntax:

  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -c ext/libxml/extconf.rb

RDoc is not a full Ruby parser and will fail when fed invalid ruby programs.

The internal error was:

 (NoMethodError) undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Try to reinstall rdoc: https://github.com/ruby/rdoc/issues/786#issuecomment-757450232

Comment: Or skip the rdoc installation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562582/issue-occurring-while-installing-gem

Comment: So I tried that but I still get this warning

Comment: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-4.0.4/lib/psych.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-4.0.4/lib/psych.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-4.0.4/lib/psych.bundle (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:117:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-4.0.4/lib/psych.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: So how can I fix this

Comment: A follow up question have been posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085362/how-can-i-fix-this-psych-error-reading-ruby-and-cocoapods