# How can I fix this psych error reading ruby and cocoapods?

Tags: ruby, flutter, dart, cocoapods

This is the output if I do anything

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': 
   dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.2.2/lib/date_core.bundle, 0x0009): 
    tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.2.2/lib/date_core.bundle' 
     (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) - 
       /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.2.2/lib/date_core.bundle (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.2.2/lib/date.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

It works when I create new project and deploy it on to iOS simulator but not any older projects, Thanks in advance.

Comment: not 100 percent sure here would first try a 'flutter pub clean' in your flutter repo, and then if that doesnt fix it I would doulbe check your install of coca pods && do it with homebrew. good luck these issues are always rough

Comment: Still didn't work

Comment: Have a look here. If one of the solutions work for you, please post it as an answer below. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10220

Comment: More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.