# --no-ri --no-rdoc as default

Tags: rubygems

Is there a way to make the options --no-ri --no-rdoc as default so I don't have to type them anytime in my production server?

I googled for information but I cannot find anything about this.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the duplication but i searched for '--no-ri --no-rdoc' and nothing came up.