# Errors installing calabash with gem on mac

Tags: android, ruby, macos, installation, calabash

I am running "sudo gem install calabash-android" and I am getting the following error:

```
Successfully installed gherkin-2.12.2
Successfully installed multi_test-0.0.2
Successfully installed cucumber-1.3.8
Successfully installed json-1.8.1
Successfully installed retriable-1.3.3.1
Successfully installed slowhandcuke-0.0.3
Successfully installed rubyzip-0.9.9
Successfully installed awesome_print-1.2.0
Successfully installed httpclient-2.3.4.1
Successfully installed thor-0.18.1
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
Successfully installed mime-types-1.25
Successfully installed rest-client-1.6.7
Successfully installed xamarin-test-cloud-0.9.26
Successfully installed escape-0.0.4
Successfully installed calabash-android-0.4.14
16 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for gherkin-2.12.2...
Installing ri documentation for multi_test-0.0.2...
Installing ri documentation for cucumber-1.3.8...
Installing ri documentation for json-1.8.1...
Installing ri documentation for retriable-1.3.3.1...
Installing ri documentation for slowhandcuke-0.0.3...
Installing ri documentation for rubyzip-0.9.9...
Installing ri documentation for awesome_print-1.2.0...
Installing ri documentation for httpclient-2.3.4.1...


RDoc failure in lib/httpclient.rb at or around line 408 column 16

Before reporting this, could you check that the file
you're documenting compiles cleanly--RDoc is not a
full Ruby parser, and gets confused easily if fed
invalid programs.

The internal error was:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `name' for #<RubyToken::TkLPAREN:0x1049a5f38>
```

What can I do to resolve this issue? I am following the steps at this URL: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a work-around would be to install without the documentation, if you don't need it (google, ruby-doc, and stackoverflow work well, too!):

sudo gem install calabash-android --no-rdoc

it can also [be your default from now on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install)