# Suppressing the ri and rdoc

Tags: rdoc, ri

I want to suppress the downloading of ri and rdoc while i install new gems on my windows machine. On linux we can edit .gemrc file. What is a way to do it in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For window user you can use.

```
(echo install: --no-document && echo update: --no-document) >> c:\ProgramData\gemrc
```

or

```
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\gemrc
```

also you can check below link

[How to make --no-ri --no-rdoc the default for gem install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install/7662245#7662245)