# gem install rails -v 4.1.0 stuck with ri-documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems

I've run `gem install rails -v 4.1.0` on my server, but somehow it's stuck with

```
Parsing documentation for rails-4.1.0 
Installing ri documentation for rails-4.1.0
```

Can I abort this? What do I need the ri documentation for? Is it really required?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Though the documentation isn't necessary for rails to run; I have found that it is most likely **not stuck**.

It took a little over five minutes to complete `gem install rails -v 4.1.0` on my quad-core i7, but your experience might be worse if you have a slower computer (it took **15m 47s** for just ri and an additional **16m 21s** for RDoc on my 4 logical core i5). For those who want to make use of the ri and RDocs you will merely have to wait. For those who have no intent to ever use them you can execute

```
gem install rails -v 4.1.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

This took ~30s on my i5 machine.

Comment: I can confirm it can take a while - `gem rails install` took 6117 seconds -- an hour and forty minutes -- on my AMD A4-1250, and almost all of that was installing ri documentation for rails.

Answer (score 3):

You can abort it using `crtl+c`

You can use [`gem install rails --no-document`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install) to install Rails without the documentation

Comment: Ok! Yes, i have aborted it. It works fine. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends as per your use, but you can get rid of this **ri documentations** use this command

```
   gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Rails 4.2.5. I just used Ctrl+C, and then ran `gem install rails` again, and it said done.