# How can I configure RubyGems to not install rdoc or ri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I would like to arrange it so that RubyGems never, ever, under any circumstances installs rdoc or ri documentation.

I've found a variety of different approaches from different time periods scattered among various blog posts, none of which work.

I've tried the following configs in my `~/.gemrc` file...

```
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources: ['https://rubygems.org/']
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
:gem: --no-document
```

And...

```
[ ... ]
:gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

And...

```
[ ... ]
:gem: -N
```

In all cases, the result is **identical**...

```
$ gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_config
Fetching: pg-0.18.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.18.2
invalid options: -f fivefish
(invalid options are ignored)
Parsing documentation for pg-0.18.2
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.18.2
Done installing documentation for pg after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

How this is currently done?

Comment: This will answer your question :), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
install: --no-document
update: --no-document
```