# bundle install fails with rdoc Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rdoc

while trying to install a Ruby application with Bundler, the dependent rdoc gem fails with an `Internal Server Error`:

```
user@machine:/home/user/someapp# bundle
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.3)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.6.1)
Using activesupport (3.2.12)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.12)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.12)
Using mime-types (1.21)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.12)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.35)
Using activerecord (3.2.12)
Using activeresource (3.2.12)
Using addressable (2.3.3)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
Using coderay (1.0.9)
Using better_errors (0.7.0)
Using debug_inspector (0.0.2)
Using binding_of_caller (0.7.1)
Using cancan (1.6.9)
Using nokogiri (1.5.6)
Using ffi (1.4.0)
Using childprocess (0.3.8)
Using rubyzip (0.9.9)
Using websocket (1.0.7)
Using selenium-webdriver (2.30.0)
Using xpath (1.0.0)
Using capybara (2.0.2)
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Using json (1.7.7)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Internal Server Error 500 (http://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/gems/rdoc-3.12.1.gem)
An error occured while installing rdoc (3.12.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rdoc -v '3.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

What I have tried:

- gem install rdoc -v '3.12.1': `ERROR:  While executing gem ... Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) bad response Internal Server Error 500 (http://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/gems/rdoc-3.12.1.gem)`
- adding `gem: --no-document` to the `/etc/gemrc` file
- adding `gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri` to the `/etc/gemrc` file

How can I get rdoc to install, or how do I get the application to install without rdoc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make --no-ri --no-rdoc the default for gem install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install)

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling `rdoc`. Maybe there was a problem with the rubygems server when you last tried.