# Unable to generate new rails app - `load': cannot load such file -- /home/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.0/bin/rails (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm unable to run `rails new SomeApp`.

I receive the following error:

`load': cannot load such file --
 /home/captainawesome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.0/bin/rails (LoadError)`

Going through the path in: `/home/captainawesome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.0/bin/rails`, the ***bin directory does not exist***.

Also, please know I can still run the rails server and console but not `rails new app`.

My current setup

```
Ubuntu 14.04
ruby 2.2.0p0
rails 4.2.0
rvm 1.26.11
local server (not remote)
development environment
```

​

```
$ which rails
/home/captainawesome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails

$ rails -v
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to "bundle binstub rails"
to work around a system/bundle conflict.
```

Rails 4.2.0

Please know this only works inside of a project.

---

```
$ which ruby
/home/captainawesome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
```

---

```
$which rvm
/home/captainawesome/.rvm/bin/rvm

$ rvm use
Using /home/captainawesome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0

$ rvm -v
rvm 1.26.11 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Please advise on how to correct this.

Comment: Do `gem install rails`

Comment: it's asking to overwrite. Should I proceed?

Comment: Yes, it will re-install rails for you.

Comment: That worked! Unsure what would cause that error. But thank you for your help.

Comment: I've posted it as answer. If you think it helped you, you can accept it as answer. I also mentioned a good practice to follow, and a link to where you can get more information about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-install Rails, and it will solve your error:

Here's how:

```
gem install rails
```

And try to use separate gemsets for your Rails applications, this will allow you to quickly and automatically change your Ruby version and associated gems when you do `cd your_project_name`. [Here's how](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/why-you-should-use-rvm--net-19529).

Comment: yeah , uninstall already install versions and then re-installing resolves the issue

Answer (score 2):

To add to Arslan Ali's correct answer, you can also avoid *endless* installation of documentation. If you're impatient like me, do:

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

However with impatience also comes haste and forgetfulness. Luckily you can make skipping docs the default using method described in this SO post: [How to make --no-ri --no-rdoc the default for gem install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install)

Answer (score 0):

Update to B. Bulpett's answer which is deprecated, the new way of installing without documentation is

```
gem install rails -​-no-document
```