# Where is "global" .gemrc for Ruby installed with rbenv?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

Installed Ruby 2.3.1 using `rbenv` and now I want to enable

> gem: --no-document

for all users. I mean I do not want to put it into `~/.gemrc`. Here ([How to make --no-ri --no-rdoc the default for gem install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install)) I've read that this global file is `/etc/gemrc` but it does not work for me.

Tried on Mac with default Ruby 2.0.0, with Ruby installed with rbenv, inside Docker image CentOS 6.7 - no luck, `/etc/gemrc` does not work for me.

But when I copy gemrc to my home dir with `cp /etc/gemrc ~/.gemrc` and install any gem, I immediately see that documentation is no longer installed.

Where am I mistaken or maybe something changed in Ruby-world?

Answer (score 1):

The new notation is:

```
install: --no-document
```

The directives are now per `gem` command, not for `gem` itself.

Comment: Good to know. Since what version/dates? Unfortunately this still does not work if I put it into `/etc/gemrc`

Comment: `rbenv` uses different config locations since it's user-specific. It may not even look in `/etc`. I think this is since Rubygems 2.0 but I could be wrong. They've changed it back and forth a few times for reasons nobody can ever explain.