# Can gem installation can be shorter when installing Fastlane on Azure DevOps?

Tags: ruby, installation, bundler, fastlane

im using the Azure DevOps pipeline and one of ,y stages is to install ruby + Fastlane,
the problem is it takes to long and i wonder how can I shorten the procedure.
I'm not a ruby developer, I'm not sure i need all this...
this is my steps :

```
gem install bundler
bundle update --bundler
bundle install --retry=3 --jobs=4
gem install fastlane
```

the output is :

```
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4139510Z Successfully installed slack-notifier-2.3.2
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4140310Z Successfully installed atomos-0.1.3
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4140990Z Successfully installed CFPropertyList-3.0.2
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4141560Z Successfully installed claide-1.0.3
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4142130Z Successfully installed colored2-3.1.2
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4142690Z Successfully installed nanaimo-0.3.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4143240Z Successfully installed xcodeproj-1.18.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4143860Z Successfully installed rouge-2.0.7
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4144410Z Successfully installed xcpretty-0.3.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4145010Z Successfully installed terminal-notifier-2.0.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4145610Z Successfully installed unicode-display_width-1.7.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4146240Z Successfully installed terminal-table-1.8.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4146810Z Successfully installed plist-3.5.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4147400Z Successfully installed public_suffix-4.0.6
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4148010Z Successfully installed addressable-2.7.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4149100Z Successfully installed multipart-post-2.0.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4149780Z Successfully installed word_wrap-1.0.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4150340Z Successfully installed tty-screen-0.8.1
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4150950Z Successfully installed tty-cursor-0.7.1
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4151530Z Successfully installed tty-spinner-0.9.3
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4152090Z Successfully installed babosa-1.0.3
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4152640Z Successfully installed colored-1.2
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4153180Z Successfully installed highline-1.7.10
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4153810Z Successfully installed commander-fastlane-4.4.6
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4154370Z Successfully installed excon-0.76.0
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4154930Z Successfully installed faraday-1.0.1
2020-09-09T14:54:44.4155220Z Building native extensions. This could take a while...
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5303010Z Successfully installed unf_ext-0.0.7.7
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5303750Z Successfully installed unf-0.1.4
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5304400Z Successfully installed domain_name-0.5.20190701
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5305000Z Successfully installed http-cookie-1.0.3
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5305580Z Successfully installed faraday-cookie_jar-0.0.7
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5306240Z Successfully installed faraday_middleware-1.0.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5306820Z Successfully installed fastimage-2.2.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5307440Z Successfully installed gh_inspector-1.1.3
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5308010Z Successfully installed mini_magick-4.10.1
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5308590Z Successfully installed rubyzip-2.3.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5309140Z Successfully installed security-0.1.3
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5309770Z Successfully installed xcpretty-travis-formatter-1.0.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5310370Z Successfully installed dotenv-2.7.6
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5310910Z Successfully installed naturally-2.2.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5311480Z Successfully installed simctl-1.6.8
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5312010Z Successfully installed jwt-2.2.2
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5312620Z Successfully installed declarative-option-0.1.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5313820Z Successfully installed declarative-0.0.20
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5314400Z Successfully installed uber-0.1.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5314970Z Successfully installed representable-3.0.4
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5315530Z Successfully installed retriable-3.1.2
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5316150Z Successfully installed mini_mime-1.0.2
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5316710Z Successfully installed multi_json-1.15.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5317310Z Successfully installed signet-0.14.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5317870Z Successfully installed memoist-0.16.2
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5318430Z Successfully installed os-1.1.1
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5318990Z Successfully installed googleauth-0.13.1
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5319540Z Successfully installed httpclient-2.8.3
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5320190Z Successfully installed google-api-client-0.38.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5320780Z Successfully installed google-cloud-env-1.3.3
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5321390Z Successfully installed google-cloud-errors-1.0.1
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5322000Z Successfully installed google-cloud-core-1.5.0
2020-09-09T14:54:58.5322360Z Building native extensions. This could take a while...
2020-09-09T14:55:22.7201180Z invalid options: -SHN
2020-09-09T14:55:22.7201910Z (invalid options are ignored)
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8823220Z Successfully installed digest-crc-0.6.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8854440Z Successfully installed google-cloud-storage-1.28.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8855640Z Successfully installed emoji_regex-3.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8856740Z Successfully installed jmespath-1.4.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8858420Z Successfully installed aws-partitions-1.365.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8859500Z Successfully installed aws-eventstream-1.1.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8860490Z Successfully installed aws-sigv4-1.2.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8861470Z Successfully installed aws-sdk-core-3.105.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8862430Z Successfully installed aws-sdk-kms-1.37.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8864530Z Successfully installed aws-sdk-s3-1.79.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8870340Z Successfully installed fastlane-2.158.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8872330Z Parsing documentation for slack-notifier-2.3.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8873430Z Installing ri documentation for slack-notifier-2.3.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8874440Z Parsing documentation for atomos-0.1.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8875400Z Installing ri documentation for atomos-0.1.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8876470Z Parsing documentation for CFPropertyList-3.0.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8877470Z Installing ri documentation for CFPropertyList-3.0.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8878460Z Parsing documentation for claide-1.0.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8879420Z Installing ri documentation for claide-1.0.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8880430Z Parsing documentation for colored2-3.1.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8881400Z Installing ri documentation for colored2-3.1.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8882410Z Parsing documentation for nanaimo-0.3.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8883380Z Installing ri documentation for nanaimo-0.3.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8884390Z Parsing documentation for xcodeproj-1.18.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8885380Z Installing ri documentation for xcodeproj-1.18.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8886420Z Parsing documentation for rouge-2.0.7
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8887390Z Installing ri documentation for rouge-2.0.7
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8888600Z Parsing documentation for xcpretty-0.3.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8892800Z Installing ri documentation for xcpretty-0.3.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8893860Z Parsing documentation for terminal-notifier-2.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8894980Z Installing ri documentation for terminal-notifier-2.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8896350Z Parsing documentation for unicode-display_width-1.7.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8897400Z Installing ri documentation for unicode-display_width-1.7.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8898460Z Parsing documentation for terminal-table-1.8.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8899470Z Installing ri documentation for terminal-table-1.8.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8900440Z Parsing documentation for plist-3.5.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8901460Z Installing ri documentation for plist-3.5.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8906820Z Parsing documentation for public_suffix-4.0.6
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8908270Z Installing ri documentation for public_suffix-4.0.6
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8909630Z Parsing documentation for addressable-2.7.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8910640Z Installing ri documentation for addressable-2.7.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8911700Z Parsing documentation for multipart-post-2.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8912740Z Installing ri documentation for multipart-post-2.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8913770Z Parsing documentation for word_wrap-1.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8935180Z Installing ri documentation for word_wrap-1.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8977270Z Parsing documentation for tty-screen-0.8.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8983020Z Installing ri documentation for tty-screen-0.8.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8985530Z Parsing documentation for tty-cursor-0.7.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8986610Z Installing ri documentation for tty-cursor-0.7.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8987670Z Parsing documentation for tty-spinner-0.9.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8988530Z Installing ri documentation for tty-spinner-0.9.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8990970Z Parsing documentation for babosa-1.0.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8992080Z Installing ri documentation for babosa-1.0.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8993040Z Parsing documentation for colored-1.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8994000Z Installing ri documentation for colored-1.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8994950Z Parsing documentation for highline-1.7.10
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8995900Z Installing ri documentation for highline-1.7.10
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8996870Z Parsing documentation for commander-fastlane-4.4.6
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8997880Z Installing ri documentation for commander-fastlane-4.4.6
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8998830Z Parsing documentation for excon-0.76.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.8999780Z Installing ri documentation for excon-0.76.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9000720Z Parsing documentation for faraday-1.0.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9001670Z Installing ri documentation for faraday-1.0.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9002600Z Parsing documentation for unf_ext-0.0.7.7
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9003560Z Installing ri documentation for unf_ext-0.0.7.7
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9004760Z Parsing documentation for unf-0.1.4
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9006220Z Installing ri documentation for unf-0.1.4
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9007250Z Parsing documentation for domain_name-0.5.20190701
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9109080Z Installing ri documentation for domain_name-0.5.20190701
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9176150Z Parsing documentation for http-cookie-1.0.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9177670Z Installing ri documentation for http-cookie-1.0.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9178970Z Parsing documentation for faraday-cookie_jar-0.0.7
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9180070Z Installing ri documentation for faraday-cookie_jar-0.0.7
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9181080Z Parsing documentation for faraday_middleware-1.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9182090Z Installing ri documentation for faraday_middleware-1.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9183040Z Parsing documentation for fastimage-2.2.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9184000Z Installing ri documentation for fastimage-2.2.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9184940Z Parsing documentation for gh_inspector-1.1.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9185980Z Installing ri documentation for gh_inspector-1.1.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9186990Z Parsing documentation for mini_magick-4.10.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9195140Z Installing ri documentation for mini_magick-4.10.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9196160Z Parsing documentation for rubyzip-2.3.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9211000Z Installing ri documentation for rubyzip-2.3.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9211840Z Parsing documentation for security-0.1.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9212460Z Installing ri documentation for security-0.1.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9213410Z Parsing documentation for xcpretty-travis-formatter-1.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9214100Z Installing ri documentation for xcpretty-travis-formatter-1.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9214740Z Parsing documentation for dotenv-2.7.6
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9215320Z Installing ri documentation for dotenv-2.7.6
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9215930Z Parsing documentation for naturally-2.2.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9216520Z Installing ri documentation for naturally-2.2.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9217180Z Parsing documentation for simctl-1.6.8
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9218390Z Installing ri documentation for simctl-1.6.8
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9219030Z Parsing documentation for jwt-2.2.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9219620Z Installing ri documentation for jwt-2.2.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9220220Z Parsing documentation for declarative-option-0.1.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9220920Z Installing ri documentation for declarative-option-0.1.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9221530Z Parsing documentation for declarative-0.0.20
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9222160Z Installing ri documentation for declarative-0.0.20
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9222750Z Parsing documentation for uber-0.1.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9223360Z Installing ri documentation for uber-0.1.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9223970Z Parsing documentation for representable-3.0.4
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9224590Z Installing ri documentation for representable-3.0.4
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9225200Z Parsing documentation for retriable-3.1.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9225790Z Installing ri documentation for retriable-3.1.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9226430Z Parsing documentation for mini_mime-1.0.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9227050Z Installing ri documentation for mini_mime-1.0.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9227670Z Parsing documentation for multi_json-1.15.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9228280Z Installing ri documentation for multi_json-1.15.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9228880Z Parsing documentation for signet-0.14.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9229480Z Installing ri documentation for signet-0.14.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9230060Z Parsing documentation for memoist-0.16.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9230720Z Installing ri documentation for memoist-0.16.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9231290Z Parsing documentation for os-1.1.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9231920Z Installing ri documentation for os-1.1.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9232500Z Parsing documentation for googleauth-0.13.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9233150Z Installing ri documentation for googleauth-0.13.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9233760Z Parsing documentation for httpclient-2.8.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9234360Z Installing ri documentation for httpclient-2.8.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9235040Z Parsing documentation for google-api-client-0.38.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9236150Z Installing ri documentation for google-api-client-0.38.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9236960Z Parsing documentation for google-cloud-env-1.3.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9237590Z Installing ri documentation for google-cloud-env-1.3.3
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9238260Z Parsing documentation for google-cloud-errors-1.0.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9238910Z Installing ri documentation for google-cloud-errors-1.0.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9239550Z Parsing documentation for google-cloud-core-1.5.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9240190Z Installing ri documentation for google-cloud-core-1.5.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9240790Z Parsing documentation for digest-crc-0.6.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9241450Z Installing ri documentation for digest-crc-0.6.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9242070Z Parsing documentation for google-cloud-storage-1.28.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9242760Z Installing ri documentation for google-cloud-storage-1.28.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9243390Z Parsing documentation for emoji_regex-3.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9244060Z Installing ri documentation for emoji_regex-3.0.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9244680Z Parsing documentation for jmespath-1.4.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9245270Z Installing ri documentation for jmespath-1.4.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9245940Z Parsing documentation for aws-partitions-1.365.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9246570Z Installing ri documentation for aws-partitions-1.365.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9247240Z Parsing documentation for aws-eventstream-1.1.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9247860Z Installing ri documentation for aws-eventstream-1.1.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9248520Z Parsing documentation for aws-sigv4-1.2.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9249130Z Installing ri documentation for aws-sigv4-1.2.2
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9249720Z Parsing documentation for aws-sdk-core-3.105.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9250360Z Installing ri documentation for aws-sdk-core-3.105.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9250970Z Parsing documentation for aws-sdk-kms-1.37.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9251590Z Installing ri documentation for aws-sdk-kms-1.37.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9252190Z Parsing documentation for aws-sdk-s3-1.79.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9253240Z Installing ri documentation for aws-sdk-s3-1.79.1
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9253860Z Parsing documentation for fastlane-2.158.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9254500Z Installing ri documentation for fastlane-2.158.0
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9257400Z Done installing documentation for slack-notifier, atomos, CFPropertyList, claide, colored2, nanaimo, xcodeproj, rouge, xcpretty, terminal-notifier, unicode-display_width, terminal-table, plist, public_suffix, addressable, multipart-post, word_wrap, tty-screen, tty-cursor, tty-spinner, babosa, colored, highline, commander-fastlane, excon, faraday, unf_ext, unf, domain_name, http-cookie, faraday-cookie_jar, faraday_middleware, fastimage, gh_inspector, mini_magick, rubyzip, security, xcpretty-travis-formatter, dotenv, naturally, simctl, jwt, declarative-option, declarative, uber, representable, retriable, mini_mime, multi_json, signet, memoist, os, googleauth, httpclient, google-api-client, google-cloud-env, google-cloud-errors, google-cloud-core, digest-crc, google-cloud-storage, emoji_regex, jmespath, aws-partitions, aws-eventstream, aws-sigv4, aws-sdk-core, aws-sdk-kms, aws-sdk-s3, fastlane after 232 seconds
2020-09-09T14:59:09.9259210Z 69 gems installed
2020-09-09T14:59:10.0555240Z total 56
```

Comment: Also, look into pipeline caching: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

One method to speed up this process is to use the `--no-document` flag for `gem install` by editing your `~/.gemrc` file to include the following:

```
gem: --no-document
```

Alternatively, you can just add it to your `gem` commands:

```
gem install --no-document bundler
bundle update --bundler
bundle install --retry=3 --jobs=4
gem install --no-document fastlane
```

If you find that it's not working then perhaps you have an older version of Ruby and should explore [some alternative settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1381725/3784008) for older versions.

You don't need to make any changes for `bundle install` because bundler does not install documentation by default.

The documentation is clearly not the most costly step in terms of time, but cumulatively this will add up.